# How To request with ajax the facebook share page

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

How to request with ajax the facebook share page.. and  I want to show in a DIV The result which is come

Normally When I clicked the facebook share button It opening new window. But I dont want to do this.. I want open new div How can I do?

Comment: I think you are out of luck here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot AJAX and show in a DIV. However instead of pop-up, you can show it in an iframe.

Check the Display modes:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

However:

> If you specify iframe, you must have
>   a valid access_token. To get a valid
>   access_token, please see the
>   [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) guide

If you'd like to avoid this Autentication / access_token thing, then you might as well use the `page` display mode. Which should look something like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
 description=Dialogs%20provide%20a%20simple,%20consistent%20interface%20for%20applications%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

Except it will show inside your iframe. Copy everything in that code block and enter it in your adress bar.

Feed Dialogs

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/